# Selecting a date range using month and year code igniter

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter

i want to have this function where i can select all records from database by inputting only a month and current year

my database date format is 'YYYY-MM-DD'

and for example i select june for month and enter, it will search june1-june30 of the current year.

Comment: WHERE DATEPART(year,datefield) = YearVariable AND DATEPART(mm,datefield) = MonthVariable

Comment: i want the year to be the current year without inputting it

Comment: I've just posted my code as an answer, see if that meets your reqirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have no clear answer recieved so i just put up all the ideas and i came up with something like this,

`"SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE month(DATE) = ".$month." AND year(DATE) = YEAR(now())`

where month input is a number from the month e.g `1 - jan, 2 - feb,` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try building a query for the below

```
select * from thetable where monthname(date_field) = 'February'
```

or month(), if you want to return a number

```
select * from thetable where month(date_field) = 2
```

Comment: how about the year? i wanted it to be the current year without inputting something

Answer (score 0):

Here would be my solution. You can leave the Year as NULL but you then have the option to select the year should you want to.

Test Data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestData
GO
CREATE TABLE #TestData (ID int, DateField datetime)
INSERT INTO #TestData (ID, DateField)
VALUES
(1,'2016-01-01')
,(2,'2016-02-02')
,(3,'2016-01-25')
,(4,'2016-02-16')
,(5,'2015-01-12')
,(6,'2015-01-20')
```

Query

```
DECLARE @MonthVariable int; SET @MonthVariable = '1'
DECLARE @YearVariable int; SET @YearVariable = '2016'

SELECT
ID
,Datefield
FROM #TestData
WHERE DATEPART(mm,DateField) = @MonthVariable
AND (DATEPART(yy,DateField) = @YearVariable
    OR @YearVariable IS NULL)
```

Output

```
ID  Datefield
1   2016-01-01 00:00:00.000
3   2016-01-25 00:00:00.000
```

If you will ALWAYS want the current year then you can do this;

```
DECLARE @MonthVariable int; SET @MonthVariable = '1'

SELECT
ID
,Datefield
FROM #TestData
WHERE DATEPART(mm,DateField) = @MonthVariable
AND DATEPART(yy,DateField) = DATEPART(yy,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE MONTH(date_field) = MonthVariable AND YEAR(date_fied) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

GETDATE() return current day and so year and
assuming that the variable destined to month (MonthVariable) contains a number reported per month